# How to duplicate an entire dropbox directory tree to skydrive?

Tags: macos, dropbox, symlink, network

I've got a directory tree set up in my Dropbox folder.  For redundancy, I'd like to duplicate that entire tree in SkyDrive.  I'd like everything to update and sync automatically (from Dropbox to SkyDrive) so that any changes I make in the Dropbox folder (add/remove/change to files or sub-directories) get reflected in the SkyDrive folder.

I thought that a symbolic link between the top-level directories (e.g. `ln -s /Users/MyName/Desktop/Dropbox /Users/MyName/Desktop/SkyDrive`) would do it, but it's not working as I expected.  I only see the directories get linked, not the contents.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox honors symbolic links so you can use

```
ln -s ~/Desktop/SkyDrive ~/Desktop/Dropbox/
```

This creates a symbolic link `SkyDrive` inside your Dropbox folder pointing to the whole SkyDrive. All files/directories stored inside SkyDrive will be available in Dropbox as well now.

Comment: I actually wanted to go the other way (putting Dropbox inside the SkyDrive folder) but it did work the way you suggested.  Not sure if SkyDrive honors symbolic links like Dropbox does.

Comment: I don't think SkyDrive will follow symbolic links. So move all your files from Dropbox and then follow @patrix step above.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on using a hard link rather than a symbolic one? Its working for me so far and has the advantage of the link being shown in Finder as a folder rather than an alias, but I haven't found anyone else suggesting it.

Comment: Hard links on directories/folders create all sorts of problems and are only supported for Time Machine actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Dropbox to syncronise any directory tree in its Preferences see [Dropbox documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/89/en). So you could tell Dropbox to sync /Users/MyName/Desktop/SkyDrive.

However I would wonder what happens when .dropbox-cache updates - does Skydrive update and then dropbox update ie you get a continuous uploading - this applies to any way you make the directories the same.